# subnet masking related confusion

Tags: ipv4, subnet

I am new to subnet masking. I have a question. If network address is 10.10.10.0/23, what will be the first and last usable IP address of this network?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that 10.10.10.10/23 is a network address, it would be a host address on a network;  the network address would be 10.10.10.0, the subnet mask would be 255.255.254.0.

Regarding the calculations:  I always convert to binary - 10.10.10.10 is

```
00001010 00001010 00001010 00001010
```

With a 23 bit subnet mask, that's

```
11111111 11111111 11111110 00000000
```

Using it as a mask

```
11111111 11111111 11111110 00000000
00001010 00001010 00001010 00001010
```

the network address is the part below the 1's, followed by zeros:

```
00001010 00001010 00001010 00000000
```

which is 10.10.10.0

The hosts are determined by the rest of the bits.  Since the mask is 23 bits, there are 9 bits for the host portion of the addresses.  (32-23=9)

so they range from

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

to

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 11111111
```

Adding those values to the network address - the low value:

```
 00001010 00001010 00001010 00000000
+00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
____________________________________
 00001010 00001010 00001010 00000001
```

which is 10.10.10.1  - the high value:

```
 00001010 00001010 00001010 00000000
+00000000 00000000 00000001 11111111
____________________________________
 00001010 00001010 00001011 11111111
```

which is 10.10.11.255 - the broadcast address.

So the network address is 10.10.10.0 
and the broadcast address is 10.10.11.255 
and the usable addresses are 10.10.10.1 through 10.10.11.254

its easy in binary.

Comment: edited. The network address is 10.10.10.0/23 @batsplatsterson

Answer (score 0):

The range of usable hosts will be 10.10.10.1 - 10.10.11.254 with a subnet of 255.255.254.0. The 10.10.10.255 and 10.10.11.0 address will be usable in this situation.

You can run these questions through a subnet calcualtor. I use [Wintelguy](http://wintelguy.com/subnetcalc.pl)

Comment: can you please show me the details of calculation for 10.10.10.0/23 @Matthew Williams

Comment: I think you will find the accepted answer to this question useful for a full calculation: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers